# JQuery Rotating text snippets/phrases

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I am wanting to rotate text snippets with only using HTML, CSS and JQuery and have a fade in/out effect on the phrases so that as one is fading out as the next is fading in. I have the following code, but can't figure out where to add in my fade in/out effects. Or, is there a better way of rotating text snippets with fade in/out effects? I'd like to stay away from plugins as it is probably overkill to use a resource-heavy plugin. Seems like what I'm wanting to do can be pulled off with some native JQuery functions.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>I like <span id="phrase">apples</span>.</h1>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setRandomPhrase() {
        // Set phrases into an array
        var phrases = new Array(
            "oranges",
            "pears",
            "strawberries",
            "grapes",
            "pineapples",
            "bananas"
        );

        // Selects a random phrase
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);
        // Sets the area to use that random phrase
        $("#phrase").text(phrases[random]);
    }
    // Fire the function every 5 seconds...
    setInterval(setRandomPhrase,5000);
});
```

Here's a semi-working sample: http://jsbin.com/ayukac/1/edit ...just need help with figuring out where to add in fade effects.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Fade out the current fruit, then once the fade out is complete, update the value, and fade in.

...

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);

$("#phrase").fadeOut("slow",function(){
    $("#phrase").text(phrases[random]).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

...

Comment: @ParPar These answers correctly fade out the current text snippet and fade in the next, but I am trying to get them to happen at the same time. So, as one fades out the next phrase has already started fading in. The effect I'm going for is something more like a crossfade. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/ayukac/2/edit

I've also added a rudimentary check to prevent the same word appear twice in a row from your random selection.

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);

while (phrases[random] == $("#phrase").text())
  {
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);
  }
// Sets the area to use that random phrase
$("#phrase").fadeOut('slow',function(){$("#phrase").text(phrases[random]).fadeIn('slow')});
```

Answer (score 0):

The baseic `setInterval` function is like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
       // Do something every 5 seconds
 }, 5000);
```

So everything you do in `setRandomPhrase` fire then as well.
What you need to do is to is to add this:

```
$("#phrase").fadeOut("slow",function(){
      $("#phrase").text(phrases[random]).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

instead of this:

```
$("#phrase").text(phrases[random]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery why can't you go for a jQuery plugin.
If you like to do it that way you can use the following link.
[Web Ticker](http://jonmifsud.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-webticker/)